# THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost (Uncaught TypeError: unhideTextInstance is not a function)

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am rendering textured objects in `react-three-fiber` using `Suspense`:

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Image image={ images(`./texture.png`).default } /> // render plane with texture.png
    <Image image={ images(`./texture.png`).default } /> // render plane with texture.png
    <Image image={ images(`./texture.png`).default } /> // render plane with texture.png
</Suspense>
```

Where Image is a custom component that loads an image using `useLoader` and renders a plane with the image as its texture.

Normally no problems occur. But occasionally, with some combinations of images inside of `Suspense`, the canvas fails to render and I receive `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost` with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: unhideTextInstance is not a function
```

I tried handling the WebGL context loss with `gl.forceContextRestore()`, but when the WebGL context is restored, the canvas still fails to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the `TypeError` is being thrown because of the comments included inside of `Suspense`. Remove the comments and the problem is solved:

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Image image={ images(`./texture.png`).default } />
    <Image image={ images(`./texture.png`).default } />
    <Image image={ images(`./texture.png`).default } />
</Suspense>
```